# How to get binary module location on disk from the module itself?

Tags: powershell

The binary PowerShell module I'm developing needs to know its physical location on disk at the machine it is installed on.

Is it possible to get it from the `Cmdlet` class? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any .NET assembly (and a PowerShell binary module is a .NET assembly) has properties contains this information. In C#:

```
var myPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

Also in a script module `$PSScriptRoot` is the location of the current script; in V3 this appears to be set in any script.